# Identifying shower valve so as to replace handles with chrome

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

These came off my shower stall - which I just resurfaced. It's a Kohler faucet probably from late 70s or early 80s. Everything works but I am not a fan of the gold/brass finish. I would like to replace with chrome. I don't know if I'd also have to replace the stem/cartridge. The threaded part is 1-1/4" diameter.

I could get these electroplated in the desired color, but I know it would be cheaper to just replace them if I can find them.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google:  "Kohler dual handle shower control trim" .  That will get you a myriad of websites that you can peruse and some that you can call to get the trim you desire.

Comment: I did try Googling but didn't see anything comparable. I tried again with that phrase. All I see is new stuff.

Comment: Your best bet, instead of googling Kohler - call them. From my personal experience they have a terrific CS department. While you're on the phone they'll probably ask you to email or text the pics. Although they may not have exacly the same model in chrome, they may have something close that will fit your valve bodies. Worth a shot.

Comment: If you have a plumbing supply store around, go to it. They have catalogs on all the major brands and their faucets.They can find the parts and will probably order them for you.

Comment: Thank you both for those suggestions.

Comment: paint them ? :)

Comment: @rogerdpack   That is no fun.  Some of us would look at this problem and try to electroplate them ourselves at home for the real(expensive) DIY solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another hour of Googling, I was able to identify them: "Kohler Alterna Valvet"
I found an eBay listing with the photo of the same gold handles I have now.
After another hour of Googling, I found a replacement kit.

https://www.fdsupply.com/item/p021-212/

Kohler* Valvet* Kit 2 Valve. Fits Triton II* & Alterna.

Comment: It would be nice to list the manufacturer & part number of the replacement kit. It's a courtesy to save others the hours of web searching.

Comment: I had meant to include the link. Adding now.